# Multiply two polynomial in O(nlog n) time

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

In order to multiply two polynomial , we need O(n^2) complexity. Is it possible to perform the multiplication in O(nlog n) time??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm, you can do it in $O(n log_2 n)$.

Comment: can you expand your answer? I guess you FFT both inputs (O(n log n)), then... what?

Comment: @JanDvorak It is a very standard application of FFT. Too long to elaborate here, but see this resource on FFT and polynomials: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~maier/cs584/Lectures/lect07b-11-MG.pdf